# Rendering HTML inside a prop

Tags: html, reactjs

I am creating an app that has multiple section containers that are exactly the same, apart from the content inside. I am trying to create a `const` - or similar - that will render out the HTML needed for the container, and then I can simply enter the content.

I have tried the following which does render out correctly, although the HTML tags are being treated as just normal text.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

import React, { Component } from "react";

function Skills() {
 return (
  <div className="content-wrapper section-skills">
   {React.createElement(sectionWrapper, { cardContent: 
      "<h2 className=\"title\">Hello World</h2>" 
      })}
  </div>
 );
}

const sectionWrapper = props => (
 <section className="card">
  <div className="card-content">{props.cardContent}</div>
  <div className="card-footer">{props.cardFooter}</div>
 </section>
);

export default Skills;
```

Comment: You should specify the id or the element in which you want to render your React component ReactDOM.render(
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

Comment: You must be trying to learn from an old video or an old documentation , No one uses  React.createElement anymore , There is something called JSX, Just check out the latest doc and you'll be able to fix this bug yourself, trust me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to capitalize your component name.
2. Your html isn't a string, you can pass html element as a prop as shown.
3. They are considered as text because you have not enclosed your code in `<script type="text/babel" />`. I've also included babel CDN to convert react into browser-understandable javascript.
4. You need an element on your dom inside which you have to render your component. I've rendered your component in a div with id "root"

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<title>myPage</title>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src= "https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div id="root"></div>

<script type="text/babel">

const SectionWrapper = props => (
 <section className="card">
  <div className="card-content">{props.cardContent}</div>
  <div className="card-footer">{props.cardFooter}</div>
 </section>
);

function Skills() {
 return (<div className="content-wrapper section-skills">
    {React.createElement(SectionWrapper, {
      cardContent:<h2 className='title'>Hello World</h2>,
      cardFooter: <h2 className='title'>Footer</h2>
     },null)}
  </div>);
};

ReactDOM.render(<Skills />, document.getElementById('root'));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Another suggestion:**

Rather than using create-element, call the component directly and render it.

```
function Skills() {
    return (
      <div className="content-wrapper section-skills">
        <SectionWrapper
          cardContent=<h2 className='title'>Hello World</h2>
          cardFooter=<h2 className='title'>Footer</h2>
        />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I appreciate your efforts, keep going :) Hope I was helpful!

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked a charm :)